# FileNotFoundError, but file DOES EXIST

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pydicom

I am trying to load `.dcm` file in my Jupyter Notebook, but I am getting `FileNotFound` error, **even though file DOES exist**! I've checked by opening it in the DICOM viewer. Code is pretty simple:

```
image = pydicom.dcmread(dicom_filename).pixel_array
```

Here is the error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\StefanCepa995\\Desktop\\Machine Learning\\Projects\\Computer Vision\\Breast Mammography Analysis\\Data\\CBIS-DDSM\\dicom_files\\Mass-Training_Full_Mammogram_Images\\Mass-Training_P_00001_LEFT_CC\\07-20-2016-DDSM-74994\\1.000000-full mammogram images-24515\\1-1.dcm'
```

Funny part is, I've tried listing all files in `C:\\Users\\StefanCepa995\\Desktop\\Machine Learning\\Projects\\Computer Vision\\Breast Mammography Analysis\\Data\\CBIS-DDSM\\dicom_files\\` directory, and `os.walk()` lists all `.dcm` files, but when I use `os.path.exists()` on one of those files I am getting False as return value:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(cbis_ddsm_dicom_mass_train_dir):
    for f in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, f)
        print(file_path)
        print(os.path.exists(file_path))

C:\Users\StefanCepa995\Desktop\Machine Learning\Projects\Computer Vision\Breast Mammography Analysis\Data\CBIS-DDSM\dicom_files\Mass-Training_Full_Mammogram_Images\Mass-Training_P_00001_LEFT_CC\07-20-2016-DDSM-74994\1.000000-full mammogram images-24515\1-1.dcm
False
C:\Users\StefanCepa995\Desktop\Machine Learning\Projects\Computer Vision\Breast Mammography Analysis\Data\CBIS-DDSM\dicom_files\Mass-Training_Full_Mammogram_Images\Mass-Training_P_00001_LEFT_MLO\07-20-2016-DDSM-90988\1.000000-full mammogram images-80834\1-1.dcm
False
C:\Users\StefanCepa995\Desktop\Machine Learning\Projects\Computer Vision\Breast Mammography Analysis\Data\CBIS-DDSM\dicom_files\Mass-Training_Full_Mammogram_Images\Mass-Training_P_00004_LEFT_CC\07-20-2016-DDSM-95697\1.000000-full mammogram images-46540\1-1.dcm
False
C:\Users\StefanCepa995\Desktop\Machine Learning\Projects\Computer Vision\Breast Mammography Analysis\Data\CBIS-DDSM\dicom_files\Mass-Training_Full_Mammogram_Images\Mass-Training_P_00004_LEFT_MLO\07-20-2016-DDSM-20939\1.000000-full mammogram images-00162\1-1.dcm
False
```

Comment: There was something with a path limit of 260 characters in Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd

Comment: Which is a bit funny because the one file-path I looked at, is of length 261 :-)

Comment: Have I mentioned that I hate Windows? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Here are possible options: the way you entered your file path may not be compatible with Windows'. Here is a link to help with that: [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python).

In addition, I found that you could search for a file easily with two lines of code, and it would be less time-complex than using nested loops. Here is what I tried in my own code:

```
    import os.path

    # stores whether given file exists or not
    result = os.path.isfile(r'C:\Users\jindu\Coding\squid_fram1.png')
    print(result)
```

I got this reference from this site: https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-check-if-file-exists/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately not what I was looking for. Guys above answered my question.